# how to get home timeline data from twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I have developed one application.In my application i want to get twitter home timeline data and displaying listview.And i have used twitter4j library.I have searched a lot and also read twitter documentation.In taht documentation getting user timeline data by using the bellow webservice: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2".It is working fine and data will be displayed.But my requirement is getting home timeline data.In that documentation they given following webservice: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json.This is not working and home timeline data wont be displayed.please any one suggest me,how to do this.Thanks in advance

This is my oncreate code:This is my impotrs:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.dss.utils.UrltoValue;
import com.ibud.adapters.TweetList;
import twitter4j.Paging;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.json.DataObjectFactory;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

And this is my instance variables:

```
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "CjHtStxCA2toDQY6xnMwg"; // place your cosumer key here
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "jjhpODDhtl3FM26ETn7yt3Q1Wc7VdxZXequDrmwFg"; // place your consumer secret here

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    String username="";
    private String strResponse;
    private String[] strText;
    LinearLayout llTotal;
    ListView lvlist;
    List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter,btnLoginFaceBook,btnBack;
    // Update status button
    Button btnUpdateStatus;
    // Logout button
    Button btnLogoutTwitter;
    // EditText for update
    EditText txtUpdate;
    // lbl update
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;
    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;
    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    AccessToken accessToken;
    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if twitter keys are set
    if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
            || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // All UI elements
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    btnLoginFaceBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFaceBook);
    btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
    btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
    btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
    txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
    lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
    lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);

    btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            loginToTwitter();
        }
    });
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblUserName.setText("");
            lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnLoginFaceBook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    btnLoginFaceBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            Log.e("this is", "facebook onclick");
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
     * function
     * */
    btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

            // Check for blank text
            if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                // update status
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
            } else {
                // EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please    enter status message",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event for logout from twitter
     * */
    btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function
            logoutFromTwitter();
        }
    });

    /**
     * This if conditions is tested once is redirected from twitter page.
     * Parse the uri to get oAuth Verifier
     * */
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                // Get the access token
                accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                        verifier);

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                // After getting access token, access token secret
                // store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                // Hide login button
                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnLoginFaceBook.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Show Update Twitter
                lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Getting user details from twitter
                // For now i am getting his name only
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();

                Log.e("user id:", "" + userID);
                Log.e("user name:", username);

                try {
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

                    Log.e("tryyyyyyyyy:", "try");

                    // TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN
                    String twit_access_token = mSharedPreferences
                            .getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, null);

                    Log.e("access token:", twit_access_token);

                    // TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN SECRET
                    String twit_access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences
                            .getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, null);

                    Log.e("access token sec:", twit_access_token_secret);

                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    builder.setOAuthAccessToken(twit_access_token);
                    builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twit_access_token_secret);
                    builder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
                    builder.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);
                    // builder.setIncludeMyRetweetEnabled(true);
                    builder.setIncludeRTsEnabled(true);

                    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(
                            twit_access_token, twit_access_token_secret);

                    Log.e("accesstoken:", "" + accessToken);

                    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                            .getInstance(accessToken);

                    Log.e("twitter:", "" + twitter);

                    Paging paging = new Paging(200); // MAX 200 IN ONE CALL.
                                                        // SET YOUR OWN
                                                        // NUMBER <= 200
                    statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);

                    Log.e("statuses", "statuses");

                    try {

                        Log.e("tryyyyyyyyy in tryyyyyyyyyyyyyy:", "try");

                        String strInitialDataSet = DataObjectFactory
                                .getRawJSON(statuses);
                        JSONArray JATweets = new JSONArray(
                                strInitialDataSet);

                        Log.e("lengthhhhhhhhhhhh:", "" + JATweets.length());

                        for (int i = 0; i < JATweets.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject JOTweets = JATweets.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.e("TWEETS", JOTweets.toString());

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                // Displaying in xml ui
                lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username
                        + "</b>"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
            /*
             * Intent i = new Intent(this,ShareActivity.class);
             * startActivity(i);
             */
        }
    }

}// oncreate.

private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {

            Log.e("clickkkkkkkkkkk:", "authoriseeeeeee");

            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Log.e("elseeeeeeeeeeeee:", "elseeeeeeee");

        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLoginFaceBook.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Getting user details from twitter
        // For now i am getting his name only
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                // Get the access token
                accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                        verifier);

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                // After getting access token, access token secret
                // store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                Log.e("user id:", "" + userID);

                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();

                Log.e("user name:", username);

                // Hide login button
                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Displaying in xml ui
                lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username
                        + "</b>"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }

            /*
             * Intent i = new Intent(this,ShareActivity.class);
             * startActivity(i);
             */

        }

    }
}// login
```

And this is the posting tweet:

```
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);

            Log.e("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);

            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token 
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
                Log.e("Status", "> " + response.getText());

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    txtUpdate.setText("");
                }
            });

        }

    }//update.

private void logoutFromTwitter() {
        // Clear the shared preferences
        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
        e.commit();

        // After this take the appropriate action
        // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
        // You might not needed this code
        btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUserName.setText("");
        lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLoginFaceBook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        {
            //Log.e("this is","default back button..............");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
               intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               startActivity(intent);

        }
        return false;
     }
```

This is my code.Please help me where i have done mistake and this my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="back"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >


 <Button android:id="@+id/btnLoginFaceBook"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login with facebook"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

<!-- Twitter Login Button -->
<Button android:id="@+id/btnLoginTwitter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login with Twitter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

<!-- user name label -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/lblUserName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

<!-- label update status -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/lblUpdate" 
    android:text="Update Status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

 <!-- Tweet EditText -->
 <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUpdateStatus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<!-- Tweet Button -->
<Button android:id="@+id/btnUpdateStatus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tweet"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

 <!-- Twitter Logout button -->
 <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogoutTwitter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout from Twitter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your login is successful right? This: `Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());` shows you the Access Token?

Comment: yes bro it is right,I got this access token

Comment: Change this: `Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);` to `Twitter newTwitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);` And make these changes: `Log.e("twitter:", "" + newTwitter);` and `statuses = newTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);`

Comment: yes this is output.access token:444598736-tpnJF2CUMXlgvKdgo9OEyPnghakoU3XjotDNgsBj and access token sec:NXZKHPFggzAb2d2wQtLfedcXnnzHNfbpWNEIImF8O0 and accesstoken:AccessToken{screenName='null', userId=444598736} and twitter:TwitterImpl{INCLUDE_ENTITIES=PostParameter{name='include_entities', value='true', file=null, fileBody=null}, INCLUDE_RTS=PostParameter{name='include_rts', value='true', file=null, fileBody=null}} and statuses:[]

Comment: Did you make the changes and test?

Comment: Is this your import for the JSONArray: `import twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONArray;` and JSONObject: `import twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject;`? If yes, change them to `import org.json.JSONArray;` and `import org.json.JSONObject;`.

Comment: yes i changed twitter reference to newtwitter and test it,but same output i got it

Comment: It is impossible that the code won't work. I have literally copied and pasted from an app that is on Google Play. Did you check my earlier comment?

Comment: no i used import org.json.JSONArray and and import org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Post literally your entire code with the layout XML too. I am going to try it in a test project. I don't need your access tokens and other things that are private to you. I will use my own.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28747/discussion-between-venkataramana-and-iceman)

Comment: accesstoken:AccessToken{screenName='null', userId=444598736}.Here i got screenName=null.I think this is the problem,please suggest me where i have done mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. It's production code from an app of mine. I fetch 2 values for `Strings` **`TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY`** and **`TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET`** from my `strings.xml` file. While the values for `Strings` **`twit_access_token`** and **`twit_access_token_secret`** are pulled in from my `SharedPreferences` file. Replace those bits with your own method of storage.

```
try {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    // GET THE CONSUMER KEY AND SECRET KEY FROM THE STRINGS XML
    String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = getActivity().getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = getActivity().getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

    // TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN
    String twit_access_token = twitPrefs.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, null);

    // TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN SECRET
    String twit_access_token_secret = twitPrefs.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, null);

    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    builder.setOAuthAccessToken(twit_access_token);
    builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twit_access_token_secret);
    builder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    builder.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);
    builder.setIncludeMyRetweetEnabled(true);
    builder.setIncludeRTsEnabled(true);

    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(twit_access_token, twit_access_token_secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

    Paging paging = new Paging(200); // MAX 200 IN ONE CALL. SET YOUR OWN NUMBER <= 200
    statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);

    try {
        String strInitialDataSet = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(statuses);
        JSONArray JATweets = new JSONArray(strInitialDataSet);

        for (int i = 0; i < JATweets.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JOTweets = JATweets.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("TWEETS", JOTweets.toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

**NOTE 1:** The `statuses` is an instance of `List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();` that I have declared and instantiated as a global instance.

**NOTE 2:** This attribute is necessary `builder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);` if you want the result to be in the `JSON` format. If you need it without `JSON`, let me know.

**FINAL UPDATE:**

After testing the OP's entire code and debugging **literally everything** in a test application, the culprit turns out to be a single line (well, actually, 2):

```
Paging paging = new Paging(200); // MAX 200 IN ONE CALL. SET YOUR OWN NUMBER <= 200
statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

Turns out, for some reason, the Twitter API does not like the `Paging paging = new Paging(200);`. Changing that to `Paging paging = new Paging(10);` strangely enough, gave me 20 tweets. Removing the `Paging....` line entirely, gave me **19**. Weird result really. But my best guess at this time is that the application is perhaps new on the Twitter developer network (it still shows during authentication that the app cannot access *Direct Messages*).

Change that part to:

```
// Paging paging = new Paging(10);
statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
```

Comment: thank u for my response.i used your code,but i am getting JATweets lenth zero.And i used your code after authentication successed

Comment: @venkataramana: Well, update the OP with your attempt so far and lets see what I can do about it.

Comment: i got twit_access_token and twit_access_token_secret values,but JATweets lenth is zero

Comment: @venkataramana: Please update the OP with the code you are using. That will help me better understand what is happening.

Comment: @venkataramana: I know. I was baffled too. But after about an hour I finally zeroed in on the problem.

Comment: its working..using same code.but it shows old tweets in my case. sometime its showing particular user's feed. want latest 5 tweets.